# How to open a new window in windows form application

Tags: winforms, window, windows-xp, codeblocks

I am using windows xp and working in code::blocks 13.12 . I am making a game in which I need to open a new window. I heard that it is impossible to open a window in c but you can open one using windows form application. I have made many projects in c but I am a beginer in windows form application. I do not know how to open a new window in it. Can somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had searched a lot, but it is still not possible to do what you're trying to do. Automatically, when you run a program in code::blocks, a new window appears, in which the program runs.

**Windows Form Application**, is something totally different. Don't get confused.

Although, you can change the mode to full screen.